# Why does jQuery event fire when binding?

Tags: jquery

When the page loads, I get the message box saying "testing" even before I click on the button. Is this functionality normal?  I have also tried `.click` and `.on` with the same results.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Update() {
        alert("testing");
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#UpdateButton").bind(Update())
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't binding the function. You're calling the function and then binding the *output* of the function. Try clicking on your button and see if the event fires.

Instead, bind the function iteself (notice the lack of parentheses: `()`):

```
$("#UpdateButton").on('click', Update)
```

Or:

```
$("#UpdateButton").click(Update)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling this function here not binding it to a click like you are thinking..which will when it is clicked..

```
$("#UpdateButton").bind(Update());
```

This is the click event

```
    $("#UpdateButton").bind('click', Update);
OR

$("#UpdateButton").live('click', Update);  // Deprecated

OR 

$("#UpdateButton").on('click', Update);  // Use this instead
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#UpdateButton").click(function(){
Update();
});
    });
```